# JasperReports - It is possible a report to be listed several times automatically?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a report that is nothing more than an invoice with its items and data of these very same items. A feature was requested by the users area to select more than one invoice and print them into only one generated PDF.

I have looked at the JasperReports site and tried to use sub reports by copying the contents of the other JRXML (iReport source), I also tried to use this JRXML as embedded content into the another report using JSON list object on top of it, but also without success. Is it possible to be done? If so, how?

**EDITS**

**The method that generates the report:**

```
public static byte[] gerarPDFViaObjectArray(final String caminhoTemplate, final Object[] array) {
    try {
        final JRBeanArrayDataSource ds = new JRBeanArrayDataSource(array);
        final JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(caminhoTemplate, new HashMap<String, Object>(), ds);
        return JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(print);
    } catch (final JRException e) {
        PdfUtils.LOGGER.error("Erro ao gerar arquivo PDF de exportação de detalhe de pedidos.", e.toString());
        throw ComponentUtils.buildComponentException("Erro ao gerar arquivo PDF de exportação de detalhe de pedidos.");
    }
}
```

Stackoverflow is not allowing me to place the jrxml code. What I basically want to happen is that this array gets printed as one report instead of passing a unique object I want the report to be reproduced several times.

Comment: I do this every day, invoices, transportation documents ecc, you can do all with our without subreport, I do without..... use some grouping to achieve correct page break....  Then just pass the invoice's you like to print in the datasource... however like this the question is to broad, you need to get start going and if you have some specific problem create a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve with some jrxml and datasource example...

Answer (score 0):

That's really depends on what exacly you want as the end result. If your user doesn't mind to have 2 invoice in the same pdf, you could just do that, like a report of two or more invoices. You do it by just have the datasource of the report with the invoices to print. If you want only a header and many subreports as invoices you want, you probably must try a subreport of subreports.

Let me explain. You have a list of the invoice detail you want, like a detail line of your report. Each line of your subdetail, instead of being some text fields is a subreport. Hence a subreport containing another subreport.

So the first subreport is containing the list of the invoices you want and the second subreport, the details.

Comment: I'll update my question with the JRXML and the classes used to generate the report so as to provide more information for you to help me. Anyway, thanks in advance.

Comment: I was reassigned to another task and now I'm back, sorry for the late response. I placed the method code that generates the PDF and explaind myself a little better. Can you help me?